# Activate ipython notebook autocomplete in .py files

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I have a .py file shared with other colleagues that we are modifying almost in parallel. I would like to modify it with ipython notebook. Notebook opens it correctly and even interpret it with colors. Nevertheless, it does not auto complete when I'm programming.

I wonder whether is possible to activate the autocomplete on .py in notebook.

Thanks.

Comment: No, there is currently no autocompletion in the text editor that comes with Jupyter notebook. It's a very simple editor - the idea is to provide a minimal set of tools for someone whose only access to a server is through the notebook web interface. It's not meant to compete with a real desktop text editor. It may improve in future versions, though.